# AlarmManager not Starting Service

Tags: java, android

Before, the alarm manager was working. I don't think I changed anything, but now it isn't starting at all.

Here is the code where I set the alarm manager:

```
SettingsActivity.java

Intent intent;
static PendingIntent recurringDownload;

intent  = new Intent(context, UpdateScoresService.class);

recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
 Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener refreshListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    if(newValue.toString().equals("1")){ /* daily */
                        background_refresh.setSummary("Scores will be refreshed daily.");
                        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        manager.cancel(recurringDownload);
                        recurringDownload.cancel();
                        Log.e("DAILY REFRESH", " ");
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
                        if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())){
                            Log.e("AFTER", "10 AM DAILY");
                            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                        }
                        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
                    }else if(newValue.toString().equals("2")){ /* weekly */
                        Log.e("WEEKLY REFRESH", " ");
                        background_refresh.setSummary("Scores will be refreshed weekly.");
                        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        manager.cancel(recurringDownload);
                        recurringDownload.cancel();
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
                        if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())){
                            Log.e("AFTER", "10 AM WEEKLY");
                            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                        }
                        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, recurringDownload);
                    }else{ /* manually */
                        background_refresh.setSummary("Scores will be refreshed manually.");
                        Log.e("MANUAL REFRESH", " ");
                        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        manager.cancel(recurringDownload);
                        recurringDownload.cancel();

                    }
                    return true;
                }
};
```

The UpdateScoresService is here:

```
public class UpdateScoresService extends IntentService {

    public int countChanged;
    Context context = this;

    public UpdateScoresService() {
        super("UpdateScoresService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("onHandleIntent", "grabbing scores");
        countChanged = new GetAnimeScores(getApplicationContext()).refreshScores();

        if(countChanged>0){ //Display notification if any scores changed
            Log.d("Creating notification", " ");
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timeline_white_24dp);
            builder.setContentTitle("MAL Score Tracker");
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);

            if(countChanged==1){
                builder.setContentText("1 score changed since you were gone!");
            }else{
                builder.setContentText(countChanged+" scores changed since you were gone!");
            }

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Log in the SettingsActivity print but the Log in the onHandleIntent from the Service do not print. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: You might need the alarm to fire a BroadcastReciever or WakefulBroadcastReciever which then starts the service

Comment: @NickFriskel Hmm what do you mean by that? Can I see a code example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have a `BroadcastReceiver` which will be responsible for starting the service. The code for it should look something like this:

Create a BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class ReceiverToStartService extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateScoresService.class);
        ComponentName service = context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Register receiver in your Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverToStartService"/>
```

Now change the Intent in your Activity that you are passing to PendingIntent:

```
intent  = new Intent(context, ReceiverToStartService.class);
recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Nope still didn't seem to trigger. This is very weird. It was working before and I haven't touched it since I wrote it a few months ago, then when I switched to RetroFit a week ago for my network calls this seemed to have stopped working. I also changed the getService to getBroadcast if that helps but still seems like no dice.

Comment: Did you register your service in Manifest?

Comment: Yes I have it registered.